# Override prestashop admin TPL

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'am trying to override Cart Rule by adding a new field (number of codes).
I created a new class CartRule in /override/classes and I have added this line to definition array

```
'nb_codes' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt'),
```

and that work fine.
I have one issue that i cannot visualize this field in the informations.tpl even if i override this view in /override/controllers/admin/templates/cart_rules

Comment: did you add the column to the appropriate table in the database?

Comment: Yes i i added nb_codes to ps_cart_rule

Comment: hm okay, was asking since you hadn't mentioned it. Did you delete `cache/class_index.php`? Not sure if that is needed for template files but worth a try if you didn't. If that doesn't work please show your edits to `informations.tpl`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `nb_codes` as class var:

```
public $nb_codes;
```

Good luck